# How to convert CCSprite to black and white/Gray using setBlendFunc

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible make a CCSprite to black and white one using setBlendFunc ? If yes please tell how to do it.

More Details:

I have to make my game sprite (background,character) to gray salce/black and white for a certain point of time. I dont want to take another image for this. I have tried CCTexture2DMutable. But the thing is it take extra memory of the same sprite.

Is there any way to use one mask image and make all sprite to gray scale. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not mathematically correct grayscaling, but looks black & white:

```
// setup grayscaling:
GLfloat rgba[4] = { 0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f };
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE );
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_DOT3_RGB );
glTexEnvfv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR, rgba );
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB, GL_CONSTANT );
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR );
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB, GL_TEXTURE );
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR );
// ... glDrawArrays() here ...
// turn off grayscaling:
glTexEnvi (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

Insert this code into CCSprite drawing method. `0.65f` value of `rgba` is set experimentally, try to tune it.

Comment: this is the almost one i want, I tried with default.png(cocos2d imgae), but in some places it shows some black color which were not in original one.

Comment: Black color is caused by special formula of dot3 combine mode: `result.rgb = 4*(((r0-0.5)*(r1-0.5))+((g0-0.5)*(g1-0.5))+((b0-0.5)*(b1-0.5)))`. You may add some value to processing color by setting up previous environment, but it will clamp your color to white, and I could not make it working.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do so via setBlendFunc however it can be done using CCMutableTexture. If this a viable alternative, I will post the required code to do so.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I have already tried CCMutableTexture. I want to reduce the memory usage. Is there any use a single mask sprite and make all image to grayscale of black and white. Please excuse me if i am asking anything stupid.